# How to call constructor when moving back to the home screen in React Navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have a `createBottomTabNavigator` that has a `createStackNavigator` in it:

```
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  SettingsScreen: {
    screen: SettingsClass,  //1st screen
  },
  EditProfile: {
    screen: EditProfileClass . //2nd screen
  },
},
```

When i move back from the EditProfile screen to the main SettingsScreen, i would like to have the componentWillMount() in the SettingsScreen run again  (and each time i go back). Right now it just runs once only. OR create a function in SettingsScreen which runs when i navigate back from the EditProfile screen back to the main SettingsScreen. This is so that my main settings screen now refreshes with the latest profile information. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could add `didFocus` listener in `SettingsScreen`

```
class SettingsScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      // Call your refresh code here
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.focusListener.remove();
  }
}
```